# Angular 2/4 - Carousel & jQuery plugins

Tags: angular

I've seen some similar questions on GitHub regarding owl-carousel and carousels in general. However they do not answer my questions.

I am building a basic website, and at one point of time I need a carousel which can hold multiple images, and work like `owl-carousel` or `slick`.

Those plugins are some examples of thousands of jQuery plugins which makes it easier to build the web (when not using angular 2/4).

I would like to use jQuery plugins, however I am not aware of the issues and challenges I will be getting when using them.

Here is a list of my questions regarding `Angular 2/4`:

- Should I use jQuery plugins when there is no alternative?
- What will I loose if I do use jQuery plugins?
- If I use jQuery plugins in the best way, will I still be able to use `Angular Universal`?
- What alternatives are there?

Answer (score 1):

You're welcome to use jQuery plugins when there are no other alternatives, but there's almost *always* a better alternative than most strict JS jQuery plugins.

If you use jQuery plugins you lose many key interactions that Angular uses to create quick and compact rendering that is cross-browser compatible.

The best alternative for carousels is going to be Bootstrap - Carousel. Bootstrap is often built into most Angular boilerplates and templates that you find on GitHub. Check out https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started and https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel. It offers quick implementation for an Angular based carousel.

Comment: Yes, but bootstrap-carousel does not support all the features I need (let's say: many items on same slide as owl-carousel does)

Comment: Is there a specific list of `key interactions` angular provides which I will be loosing when using Angular?

Comment: The main thing is that you won't easily be able to directly inject a service into a jQuery plugin carousel w/o building the directives yourself. You can put many items in one slide by injecting each as a service to a single slide id with bootstrap's. The general idea is that the ng-carousel can directly integrate services, and with JiT users only download what is needed. Other plugins will likely to load everything at once, which will slow down your app speed in general.

Comment: ng-carousel is for angularjs

Comment: The links I sent require Angular 4+. The carousel directive is NgbCarousel.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a nice owl-carousel-like plugin for angular with nice animations and lazyload options. This is npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-carousel and demos are here https://sheikalthaf.github.io/ngx-carousel. I guess this is best fit for nowadays since Material team is not thinking about carousels.

Edit: I just tried to use in my project but, it is poorly designed.